# retrieve ID of inserted row (cshtml)

Tags: sql, sql-server, razor, webmatrix

I've read loads of threads on this and have tried loads of things but can't retrieve the ID of the row I have inserted (it is an auto-generating primary key on SQL Server 2008)

What is wrong with the following code please?

> ```
> public static int AddAddress(dynamic Address)
> {
>       var sql = "INSERT INTO Address (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3,      
>         TownCity, CountyID, Postcode, CountryID) VALUES (@0, @1,> @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)";
>
>       DB.Execute(sql, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, 
>          Address.AddressLine3, Address.TownCity, Address.CountyID, Address.Postcode, 
>          Address.CountryID);
>
>        return = (int)DB.GetLastInsertId();
> }
> ```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: Sorry.....I'm going to edit out that second bit from my question because I can see issues with it because it is from older versions and has been commented out ages.

Comment: "What is wrong with the following code please?" Yeah, what is wrong with it? You didn't say and I don't see anything obvious. **What is the actual problem?** What is "DB"?

Comment: Just read the question yourself. There is not enough information to even see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
return = (int)DB.GetLastInsertId();
```

Yes, it didn't work. Better it didn't compile.

```
return (int)DB.GetLastInsertId();
```

And after that, please note that `>` before the @2 in the SQL text
what does it means?

Comment: Thank-you. (I'll try to be clearer next time). I have removed the "=" and the random ">". I now get the following error "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'int'" (But i can see in SQL server that the row was successfully added so is really there, not NULL as the error would suggest). thx

Comment: Do not underestimate that error message. Something is wrong there. One of your fields is null and this message will not go away by itself. Put a breakpoint on the DB.Execute line and check the values passed to the INSERT statement

Comment: Hi. I's STILL stuck on this and am VERY frustrated. I have moved from Webmatrix to Visual Studio Express for better debugging. I can se that my dynamic Address object has the correct values in all variables passed to the execute command. I can also see in SQL Server Managment stodio that the are all saved to the table fine....no NULLS anywhere. Just the GetLastInsertId isn't working.....could I be missing anything in my website itself or SQL server that means this function is unavailable to me? THX

Comment: What's the name of your Identity column on SQLServer? It contains the next value as expected?

Comment: AddressID (Bigint, NOT Null, Identity Specification =Yes).

Comment: It contains the next value correctly (ad all other fields populated correctly

Comment: BigInt are long in C#. You force a cast to int and return an int from that method. Try to change the return value to long. (Better, assign the return value of GetLastInsertID to a long var and check if the value assigned is correct) then return that long var

Comment: Cannot convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'long' :o(

Comment: As a last resort I would try to change the AddressID column to int. (4billions of addresses should be enough)

Comment: Still the same. I changed it to int in SQL Server Management Studio, saved, closed. Also restarted Visual Studio Express. Still get: Cannot convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'int'. The GetLastInsertID() really is getting nothing for some reason (tried all variations of Scope_identity a few days ago with same sort of result).

Comment: Is it possible that INSERT _triggers_ some code inside SQLServer thus changing the result value of GetLastInsertID ? I can't see anything wrong in your example

Comment: No. I have only defined tables nothing else at all. Glad it's not just me but VERY annoyed at it not working. How bad would it be to resort to a select using all the same columns after the insert in terms of performance?

Comment: I don't know what happens here. Looked at internal source code of Db.GetLastInsertID() and it calls `Db.QueryValue("select @@identity, new object[0])`. Try to call yourself in this way `var result = Db.QueryValue("select @@identity", null)`